# web2py append dictionary to list

Tags: list, dictionary, web2py

I create a list of dictionaries from excel. The code is listed below. What happens is the list contains the last row excel values for all the rows. I tried in python shell. It works fine. Why all the rows get updated with last row values?

```
d = {}
l = []
up = os.path.join(request.folder,'uploads')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(request.folder,'uploads','meas.xls'))
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
    #print 'Row:', curr_row
    curr_cell = -1
    while curr_cell < num_cells:
        curr_cell += 1
        # Cell Types: 0=Empty, 1=Text, 2=Number, 3=Date, 4=Boolean, 5=Error, 6=Blank
        cell_type = worksheet.cell_type(curr_row, curr_cell)
        cell_value = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)
        #print '    ', cell_type, ':', cell_value
        if curr_cell == 0:
            d['loc_of_work'] = cell_value
        if curr_cell == 1:
            d['n'] = cell_value
        if curr_cell == 2:
            d['t'] = cell_value
        if curr_cell == 3:
            d['l'] = cell_value
        if curr_cell == 4:
            d['b'] = cell_value
        if curr_cell == 5:
            d['d'] = cell_value
    print 'dict'
    print d.items()
    l.append(d)
    print 'len of list:'
    print len(l)
    print 'list:'
    for i,j in enumerate(l):
        print i,j
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are declaring d outside the while loop, which means within the loop you are simply overwriting the same dict with new values on every iteration. Your list simply contains multiple references to the same dict object, which contains the values from the last row because those are the last values to be written to the dict (all previous values are overwritten)

moveoing:

```
d = {}
```

inside the first while loop should fix your issue